# App crashes on app start with error java.lang.RuntimeException:

Tags: java, android

I have some problem with device galaxy s5 and ImageButton - (On other devices it works good).

On my login activity i have ImageButton, so when I running app , it crashes.

Quistion updated: Added all the log from logcat

Here is a XML of the button - Starting from line 53

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btnNext"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="150dp"
    android:background="@null"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/next_button" />
```

and Log:

```
02-01 16:54:58.392 11521-11521/com.enjoyapp.gettmarried E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.enjoyapp.gettmarried, PID: 11521
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.enjoyapp.gettmarried/com.enjoyapp.gettmarried.ui.activities.LoginActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #53: Binary XML file line #53: Error inflating class ImageButton
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3253)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #53: Binary XML file line #53: Error inflating class ImageButton
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:551)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161)
        at com.enjoyapp.gettmarried.ui.activities.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:49)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6876)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3206)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #53: Error inflating class ImageButton
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:794)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:847)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:527)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161) 
        at com.enjoyapp.gettmarried.ui.activities.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:49) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6876) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3206) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource "com.enjoyapp.gettmarried:drawable/next_button" (7f06007e) is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f06007e a=-1 r=0x7f06007e}
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:4178)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:4085)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3935)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:886)
        at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:157)
        at android.widget.ImageButton.<init>(ImageButton.java:85)
        at android.widget.ImageButton.<init>(ImageButton.java:81)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageButton.<init>(AppCompatImageButton.java:73)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageButton.<init>(AppCompatImageButton.java:69)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createImageButton(AppCompatViewInflater.java:207)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:123)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1407)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1457)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:758)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:847) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:527) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161) 
        at com.enjoyapp.gettmarried.ui.activities.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:49) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6876) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3206) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Gradle :

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.enjoyapp.gettmarried"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

Device info : 
Galaxy s5, android version - 6.0

Comment: There should be a lot more to the stack trace, including one or more "Caused by" stanzas, that provide more details about what went wrong.

Comment: HHi @CommonsWare , I'm updated the code

Comment: That device does not like your `next_button` drawable resource for some reason. Is there anything unusual about it?

Comment: @CommonsWare I've tried to change the image to another one, still same error

Comment: Something wrong with your "next_button" drawable resource, make sure that it exists under path: "drawable/next_button", also could you show your code of "next_button" resource?

Comment: @easy_breezy Thanks for your answer, the problem is that the all other devices works good.

Comment: you need to create the same res for v23 as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try with **`android:src`** instead of **app:srcCompat**. in set of your next button image. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found the problem:

```
  Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException:
  Resource"com.enjoyapp.gettmarried:drawable/next_button" (7f06007e) is not a 
  Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f06007e a=-1 r=0x7f06007e}
```

Pay attention to your `next_button` or change `srcCompat` to `src` or `background`.